# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 " at path "_id" for model "Page"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm building an app with node/express/mongo/mongoose. I've encountered an error that I can't seem to figure out and googling around has so far not been helpful.

I've tried to create an edit page and I'd encountered an error.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cmscart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.10"
  }
}
```

**edit_page.ejs**

```
<%- include('../_layouts/adminheader')  %>

    <h2 class="page-title">Edit a Page</h2>
    <a href="/admin/pages" class="btn btn-primary">Back to all Pages</a>
    <br>
    <br>

    <form method="post" action="/admin/pages/edit-page/<%= slug %> ">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="<%= title %>" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Slug</label>
            <input type="text" name="slug" value="<%= slug %>" class="form-control" placeholder="Slug">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Content</label>
            <textarea name="content" class="form-control" placeholder="Content" rows="10" cols="30"><%= content %></textarea>

        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= id %> ">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>


<%- include('../_layouts/adminfooter')  %>
```

**admin_pages.js**

```
/* GET edit page*/

/*  here after edit page "/:slug" because we didn't have a fixed value of url*/
router.get('/edit-page/:slug', function (req, res) {

    Page.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }, function (err, page) {

        if (err) return console.log(err);

        res.render('admin/edit_page', {
            title: page.title,
            slug: page.slug,
            content: page.content,
            id: page._id
        });
    });


});




/* POST edit page*/



router.post('/edit-page/:slug', function (req, res) {
    req.checkBody('title', 'Title must have a value').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('content', 'Content must have a value').notEmpty();

    var title = req.body.title;
    var slug = req.body.slug.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    if (slug == "") slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

    var content = req.body.content;
    var id = req.body.id;


    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.render('admin/edit_page', {
            errors: errors,
            title: title,
            slug: slug,
            content: content,
            id: id
        });
    } else {
        Page.findOne({ slug: slug, _id: { '$ne': id } }, function (err, page) {

            if (page) {
                req.flash('danger', 'Page slug exists , choose another.');
                res.render('admin/edit_page', {
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    content: content,
                    id:id
                });
            }
            else {
                Page.findByIdAndUpdate(id, function (err, page) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    page.title = title;
                    page.slug = slug;
                    page.content = content;


                    page.save(function (err) {
                        if (err)
                            return console.log(err);
                        req.flash('success', 'Page added!');
                        res.redirect('/admin/pages');

                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }


});
```

In this i've encountered this error

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 " at path "_id" for model "Page"
    at new CastError (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:29:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:156:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:763:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1166:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1156:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1135:15)
    at cast (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:306:32)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4024:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1690:10)
    at model.Query.Query._findOne (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1926:8)
    at process.nextTick (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\kareem\index.js:369:33)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 " at path "_id" for model "Page"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 "',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 ',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model:
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
     base:
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Array],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
        plugins: [Array] },
     modelName: 'Page',
     model: [Function: model],
     db:
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        relatedDbs: {},
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        '$internalEmitter': [Object],
        _listening: false,
        _connectionOptions: [Object],
        name: 'cmscart',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        client: [Object],
        '$initialConnection': [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     '$appliedMethods': true,
     '$appliedHooks': true,
     schema:
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        methodOptions: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        plugins: [Array],
        '$id': 1,
        s: [Object],
        _userProvidedOptions: {},
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
     collection:
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'pages',
        collectionName: 'pages',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     '$init': Promise { [Circular] },
     '$caught': true } }
{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 " at path "_id" for model "Page"
    at new CastError (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:29:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:156:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:763:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1166:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1156:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1135:15)
    at cast (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:306:32)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4024:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1690:10)
    at model.Query.Query._findOne (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1926:8)
    at process.nextTick (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\kareem\index.js:369:33)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 " at path "_id" for model "Page"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 "',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 ',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model:
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
     base:
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Array],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
        plugins: [Array] },
     modelName: 'Page',
     model: [Function: model],
     db:
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        relatedDbs: {},
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        '$internalEmitter': [Object],
        _listening: false,
        _connectionOptions: [Object],
        name: 'cmscart',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        client: [Object],
        '$initialConnection': [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     '$appliedMethods': true,
     '$appliedHooks': true,
     schema:
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        methodOptions: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        plugins: [Array],
        '$id': 1,
        s: [Object],
        _userProvidedOptions: {},
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
        _requiredpaths: [Array] },
     collection:
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'pages',
        collectionName: 'pages',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     '$init': Promise { [Circular] },
     '$caught': true } }
{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 " at path "_id" for model "Page"
    at new CastError (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:29:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:156:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:763:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1166:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1156:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1135:15)
    at cast (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:306:32)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4024:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1690:10)
    at model.Query.Query._findOne (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1926:8)
    at process.nextTick (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\kareem\index.js:369:33)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 " at path "_id" for model "Page"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 "',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 ',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model:
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
     base:
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Array],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
        plugins: [Array] },
     modelName: 'Page',
     model: [Function: model],
     db:
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        relatedDbs: {},
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        '$internalEmitter': [Object],
        _listening: false,
        _connectionOptions: [Object],
        name: 'cmscart',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        client: [Object],
        '$initialConnection': [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     '$appliedMethods': true,
     '$appliedHooks': true,
     schema:
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        methodOptions: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        plugins: [Array],
        '$id': 1,
        s: [Object],
        _userProvidedOptions: {},
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
        _requiredpaths: [Array] },
     collection:
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'pages',
        collectionName: 'pages',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     '$init': Promise { [Circular] },
     '$caught': true } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an space character at the end of `"5be86bf8170c2c22f8bb93a6 "`. Do you try trim it first?

in file `D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\kareem\index.js` line 369 use `id.trim()` instead of `id` and any where you are using, or you can first correct the `id` at the beginning

Comment: how  i trim this